# Xcode: Launch screen changes color without premission

Tags: ios, xcode, launch

After adding launch screen, I discovered the color of it is slightly different than what I specify, I chose R:31,G:174,B:240,A:1, but I noticed it is slightly a different color on the device (I took a screenshot and used a color picker to determine what color it is exactly), this drives me crazy, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

try setting the numbers over 255.

so:

```
UIColor(red: 31/255, green: 174/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

RGB is based of 255 and need a floatNumber.

Comment: I encountered this very same issue yesterday. RGB colors are expressed as fractions w/ 255 as the denominator.

Comment: Thats what i do but the problem is there

Comment: That's strange because that's how the RGB works. Perhaps It's the color resolution on your screen. The color is not the same on my MacBook Pro vs my Asus screen. Then i run it on my iPhone to get the actual color. Do you have multiple screen.